# Angular 6 - Cannot add headers to httpClient (httpClient - @angular/common/http)

Tags: angular6

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    "Content-Type" : "application/json",
    "Authorization": "JWT Token"
  })
};
```

// http call

```
return this.http.get(apiUrl, httpOptions).pipe(
      map(this.extractData),
      catchError(this.handleError));
```

this request work but headers not pass to server. Seems like can not pass headers using @angular/common/http

---

```
const authHeaders =  new HttpHeaders();
authHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
authHeaders.append("Authorization", "Bearer " + "token");

const tt = authHeaders.get("Content-Type");
const pp = authHeaders.get("Authorization");
```

When I read headers using get then it was return null. Seems like HttpHeaders class has some issue (@angular/common/http)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the header content to "Bearer" rather than "JWT token", and pass your token inside it.

```
const authHeaders =  new HttpHeaders();
authHeaders.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
authHeaders.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.token);

const httpOptions = {
  headers: authHeaders
};
```

Comment: but still header object haven't any 'Authorization' header.

Comment: After added "Authorization" header i read authHeaders.get("Authorization"). it was return null

Answer (score 0):

@angular/common/http/HttpHeaders is immutable. Then your code should be modified as follows.

```
const authHeaders =  new HttpHeaders();
authHeaders = authHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
authHeaders = authHeaders.append("Authorization", "Bearer " + "token");
```

Answer (score 0):

i have the problem same as you . but i fix it with this implementation and i have no problem now while i am working with HttpClient methods and stick header to them.

1. first:
   it is not necessary to use HttpHeaders class.
2. get token:

   ```
   let token = localStorage.getItem('token');
   ```
3. go to service that you are working with server. in all HTTP methods, there is another parameter that is an object and in this object there is key that name is headers. then the value of this key is another object that, the key : value of this object is value and header for your request.

   ```
      http.get('someurl',{
      headers: {'header1':'value1','header2':'value2'}
      });
   ```

in real example it could be like this:

```
      getOrders(){
            let token = localStorage.getItem('token');
             return this.http.get('/api/orders' , {headers: 
            {'Authorization':'Bearer ' + token}});
             }
```

with this implementation you can stick headers of token to your request.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this,

```
let headers: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
headers = headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
headers = headers.append('Authorization', '12345');

const tt = headers.get("Content-Type");
const pp = headers.get("Authorization");
```